# Problemas com permissões e antivírus para executar a aplicação

Tags: java, arquivo, jar, antivirus

Eu criei uma aplicação em Java e gerei um executável .JAR, que funciona perfeitamente, após isto eu usei o Launch4j que tranforma meu .JAR em .EXE e depois eu usei o InstallCreator para criar um instalador para a minha aplicação .EXE para ter um visual mais profissional, mas os meu clientes estão tendo dificuldade para baixar a aplicação gerada pelo InstallCreator, pois o antivírus não permite que o usuário baixe o software .EXE que está no formato do InstallCreator (no formato de um Setup) , e em alguns casos (muito raros) quando permite baixar o Setup gerado pelo InstallCreator, após instalado, o antivírus é acionado quando a aplicação é iniciada e dá um sinal de ameaça de vírus e a aplicação é bloqueada, ou para executar o .EXE instalado é necessário "Executar como administrador". e isto dificulta muito para o usuário, alguém conhece alguma forma de pegar um .JAR transformar em .EXE e criar um instalador que não gere nenhum problema com antivírus e permissões?  E depois de instalado não dê problema para ser executado?

Answer (score 1):

Tudo depende de como está o seu Jar.

Há diversas formas de obter um resultado parecido com o que deseja.

**1. Baixar arquivos Executáveis**

A maioria dos sites que destribuem executáveis os fazem na forma de zip/tar/rar (não recomendo rar por ser proprietário e tar, uma vez que seu foco é o Windows).

**2. Pode criar um [arquivo auto extraível](http://tecnologia.culturamix.com/tecnologias/o-que-e-um-arquivo-zip-auto-extraivel) e gerar o seu jar como auto executável**

Não é necessário converter para EXE para rodar direto em Windows.

**3. Usar outro programa para fazer/criar o instalativo ou fazê-lo usando jars que são executáveis.**

Desta forma não precisará de direitos administrativos.

**4. Utilizar o desenvolvimento nativo**

Sei que está disponível para [JavaFX](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx) e [Swing](https://today.java.net/article/2003/12/04/make-your-swing-app-go-native-part-2).